# About the order of a difference equation

Tags: discrete-signals

The question is related to a statement in a dsp book.  I am attaching the image of the statement.  In the attached image, is the equation 1.5 a difference equation of order 1 as stated in the book?  I think it is of order 0 since there is no feedback term i.e. no y(n-1).  [image]

Comment: "Order" does not mean just delayed versions of the output, it also refers to delayed versions of the input.  The order of a system is the maximum delay of either input or output required to implement the system.  So $x[n] + b x[n-M]$ is of $M^{\rm th}$ order.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the order of a difference equation is equal to the maximum delay, regardless if its delay on the input or output side. So, you have two first-order difference equations here.